# Laravel Livewire accessing json attribute fails with type error

Tags: php, casting, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have a model with some typical columns and one json column. The Json is casted as array:

Model:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'client' => 'array'
];
```

In my Livewire component, I created the following validation rule

Livewire component:

```php
protected $rules = [
  'editing.name' => 'required',

  ...

  'editing.client' => 'present|array',
  'editing.client.*.tenant' => 'required',
];
```

I call the 'editModal' method where I type-hint the model and set a public property with it's attributes. Already filtered to the specific item.

Livewire component:

```php
public function editModal(TokenCacheProvider $provider)
{
    $this->editing = $provider;
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('open-modal', ['modal' => 'edit']);
}
```

My blade is a simple boiler blade component:

Blade:

```html
<div>
    <x-input.group inline borderless for="name" label="Name" :error="$errors->first('editing.name')"/>
    <x-input.text name="name" class="w-full" wire:model="editing.name" />
</div>

<div>
    <x-input.group inline borderless for="name" label="Tenant" :error="$errors->first('editing.client.tenant')"/>
    <x-input.text name="tenant" class="w-full" wire:model="editing.client.tenant" />
</div>
```

Once I load the page I get the following type exception

```
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given
```

This is because the client attribute is still a string as in the database. It should be an array as I casted it:

[image: public $editing]

So, I don't understand why the `client` attribute is still a string and not an array as casted.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try casting as `json`?

Comment: yes, I've tried both, json and array

Comment: Did you try decoding it in the livewire object? https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/json-with-livewire/1420/2

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the mentioned question because my question related to model attribute casting and not converting a json response from an API.

Comment: I can decode it in the component and store it in a seperate property. But the reason of casing attributes is to not need to handle them separately

Comment: See here; https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1826 It is an issue of Livewire. I think the fastest workaround is decoding in the livewire object. Encoding could work as normal with casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's more a work-around than a solution but [Daantje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536590/daantje) found an Livewire issue on [Github](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1826) which might explain this behavior.

I've changed the architecture from one to two public properties. One for the actual model and a second for the json column.

Livewire component (truncated)

```php
public MyModel $editing; // the model
public array $client; // for the json attribute

protected $rules = [
'editing.name' => 'required',
 ...

'client.foo' => 'required',
'client.bar' => 'required',
'client.baz' => 'required',
 ...
];


public function editModal(MyModel $model)
{
    $this->editing = $model;
    $this->client = json_decode($model->client,true);
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('open-modal', ['modal' => 'edit']);
}


public function save()
{
    $this->validate();

    $this->editing->client = json_encode($this->client);

    $this->editing->save();

    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal', ['modal' => 'edit']);

    $this->event('Saved', 'success');
}
```

Two blade input field examples:

```html
<!-- ORM field(s) -->
<div>
    <x-input.group inline borderless for="name" label="Name" :error="$errors->first('editing.name')"/>
    <x-input.text name="name" wire:model="editing.name" />
</div>


<!-- Json field(s) -->
<div>
    <x-input.group inline borderless for="foo" label="Foo" :error="$errors->first('client.foo')"/>
    <x-input.text name="foo" wire:model="client.foo" />
</div>
```

Well, this works but as mentioned it's more a workaround